# Polymorphism makes function inaccessible

Tags: c++, class, function, polymorphism

I have a map of `Shopable`s which has things in it that were initialised like this:

```
Shopable* something = new Consumable();
```

`Consumable` has a function `Heal`, but Shopable doesn't. I need the map to stay as a `Shopable` map for some function parameter, but when I try and do:

```
consumables[itemName]->Heal(this);
```

in another function, it says "Class 'Shopable' has no member 'Heal'".

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either dynamic_cast, or create a virtual dummy Heal under Shopable.

```
Consumable *con = dynamic_cast<Consumable*>(consumables[itemName]);
if(con)
    con->Heal();
//else this shopable is not really a consumable
```

Alternatively, create a virtual function called Heal() under Shopable, with nothing in it. Or with a debugger warning in it (like assert(0)), so that you know if it's called by accident. Or make a pure virtual (`virtual void Heal() = 0;`), then your prorgam will crash if it's called.

Comment: The trouble is Shopable is the base class, and three other things inherit from it and only one of them heal. With general OOP programming standards, would it still be advisable to put a pure virtual function in Shopable?

Comment: Okay then. I've never used it before - care to explain what it does?

Comment: It lets you cast object pointers from one class to another, making sure that the object is really an instance of the cast target class (or derived). If it's not, dynamic_cast returns null. In order for it to work, the source class must have at least one virtual function. http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/keywords/dynamic_cast

Comment: Is that example supposed to be `Consumable* con = dynamic_cast<Consumable*>(consumables[itemName]);`?

Answer (score 3):

Polymorphism only allows virtual dispatch of virtual functions that exist in the base class. You cannot call a function on a base class that does not exist in the base class, just because it might exist in the derived class.

In addition, you should really mean `Shoppable* something = new Consumable();` unless `Shoppable` itself is just a typedef for some pointer type.

Answer (score 1):

Is Heal something that every Shoppable should be able to do? If so, you should declare it as a [pure virtual function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function#C.2B.2B_2) in Shoppable and implement it in all subclasses.

Comment: @Pig Head: Then you should consider if putting them in the same collection *really* is the right thing to do. If your answer is yes, I urge you to check out the [Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) which essentially enables your Shoppable objects to determine if an action applies to them, e.g. someShoppable->Visit(new HealAction()); The implementation of Visit() in Consumables() knows about HealAction and allows the action to perform the action, while the base implemention in Shoppable does not, ignoring the action.

Answer (score 1):

Make Heal() a pure virtual on Shopable?

Answer (score 1):

If Heal() does only apply to a specific class that was derived from Consumable then you should go with Alekseyev's solution of using dynamic_cast.

You will need to enable RTTI if it's not yet enabled and for performance critical code dynamic_cast can have a negative impact.

You might want to have a look at [this site](http://www.devx.com/getHelpOn/Article/10202/1954) which explains the basics of RTTI in C++.